# TokenHelper - Could not find token mapped to token name struts.token

Tags: java, multithreading, struts2, token, struts2-interceptors

If I add the `"execAndWait"` interceptor, it gives me the above error:

```
TokenHelper - Could not find token mapped to token name struts.token
```

**Configuration:**

```
<action name="flightsearch" method="getFlightResult"
    class="com.test.FlightSearchAction">
    
    <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait">
        <param name="delay">500</param>
        <param name="delaySleepInterval">500</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <!--  <interceptor-ref name="token">
        <param name="excludeMethods">getFlightResult</param>
    </interceptor-ref> -->
    <result name="wait" type="tiles">flightwait</result>
    <result name="success" type="tiles">flightsearchresult</result>
</action>

<interceptors>
    <interceptor-stack name="tokenCheck">
        <interceptor-ref name="token" />
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <interceptor-ref name="basicStackHibernate" />
    </interceptor-stack>
    
    <interceptor-stack name="loggingRequired">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <interceptor-ref name="basicStackHibernate" />
    </interceptor-stack>
    
</interceptors>
```

As I have read, someone says this is an warning, and we can avoid it by changing the `TokenHelper` class. If so how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This warning appears only if `ActionContext` contains the parameter `token`. Remove this parameter before the `execAndWait` interceptor.

```
ActionContext.getContext().getParameters().remove("token");
```

BTW, the `execAndWait` interceptor should start after the `completeStack`. For example

```
<action name="someAction" class="com.examples.SomeAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="completeStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait"/>
    <result name="wait">wait.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Adding the complete stack is fine but do we get a not null result for "ActionContext.getContext()". Following link's important section says we have to use sessionaware . isn't it http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html

Comment: This is in case if you want to have an access to the session, but I didn't want to access the session.